# Django on SQL Server database filters

Tags: sql-server, django, filter, pyodbc

I need to filter data from a SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Edition database which isn't mine so I can't change it.

My problem is this:

```
mymodel.objects.get(id=1)
```

works fine

```
mymodel.objects.filter(id=1)
```

return an empty QuerySet '[]' and

```
mymodel.objects.all()
```

do the same.

This is myproject/settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc' ,
        'NAME': 'QuaniVB',             
        'USER': 'sa',                  
        'PASSWORD': '****',         
        'PORT': '1433' ,            
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'driver': 'FreeTDS',
                    'dsn' : 'MSSQL-QUANI',
        }
    },
  'emanager2': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc' , 
        'NAME': 'emanager',             
        'USER': 'sa',                   
        'PASSWORD': '******',               
        'HOST' : 'emanager2' ,
        'PORT': '1433' ,   
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'dsn' : 'MSSQL-EMANAGER2', ## as in /etc/odbc.ini
        }
    },
}
```

that's the model

```
class Medico(models.Model):
    tipo_medico = models.TextField(db_column='TIPO_MEDICO', blank=True) 
    id_medico = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='ID_MEDICO')
    cod_regionale_medico = models.TextField(db_column='COD_REGIONALE_MEDICO', blank=True)
    cognome = models.TextField(db_column='COGNOME', blank=True)
    nome = models.TextField(db_column='NOME', blank=True) 
    codfisc_medico = models.TextField(db_column='CODFISC_MEDICO', blank=True) 
    reg_ulss_appartenenza = models.TextField(db_column='REG_ULSS_APPARTENENZA', blank=True) 
    cod_individuale = models.TextField(db_column='COD_INDIVIDUALE', blank=True) 
    id_comune_ambulatorio = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, null=True, max_digits=18, db_column='ID_COMUNE_AMBULATORIO', blank=True) 
    cod_unita_med = models.TextField(db_column='COD_UNITA_MED', blank=True) 
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'MEDICO'
```

that's my 'python manage.py shell' test

```
>>> from myapp.models import Medico
>>> med = Medico.objects.using('emanager2')
>>> med.get(id_medico= 11746).cognome
>>> med.filter(id_medico= 11746)
[]
>>> med.all()
[]
>>>
```

Any suggestions on

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the raw SQL that Django generates

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> from myapp.models import Medico
>>> Medico.objects.using('emanager2').get(id=1) # you said this one works
<Medico object>
>>> connection['emanager2'].queries
[{u'sql': u'YOUR SQL WILL BE HERE', u'time': u'0.117'}]
>>> Medico.objects.using('emanager2').all() # you said this one didn't work
[]
>>> connection['emanager2'].queries
... more SQL printed here
```

Comment: my conncection queries looks like this... >>> print connection.queries
[]
an empty list

Comment: @francesco I've updated the answer. Also, you need to make sure DEBUG is on for this.

Comment: However if i execute in another client the result of  >>> Medico.objects.using('emanager2').query  it extracts all the right records

Comment: The previous was executed in debugshell and the DEBUG is True in myproject/settings.py

Comment: What do you mean by 'in another client'? Is this another shell? How is it different?

Comment: Coming back form holiday now.... Another client is OracleSqlDeveloper via JDBC or directly SQL Server Managment Studio